# После включения ЧПУ перестал работать модуль Фильтр и Сортировка в каталоге OpenCart

Tags: веб-программирование, opencart, opencart2.0

Столкнулся с проблемой на версии 2.1.0.2. Если в админке поставить ЧПУ, то перестает работать модуль Фильтр и Сортировка на странице Каталога. Подскажите, как это можно исправить? С отключенными ЧПУ все работает, но все же необходимо ссылки привести в нормальный вид.

Comment: Кэш сбрасывали? Файл htaccess в корне переименовывали?

Comment: Кэш сбросил, в htaccess убрал приставку .txt

Comment: Файл `htaccess.txt` надо переименовать в `.htaccess`

Comment: Так и сделал, не помогло(

Comment: Мало информации. Что за модуль используется для фильтрации и сортировки? Работает ли ЧПУ просто в каталоге? Какой модуль используется для ЧПУ?

Comment: Стандартный модуль Фильтр, сортировка без модулей, то есть стандартная, которая есть на странице Каталога. Устанавливаю ЧПУ через админку, то есть просто отмечаю включить, пробовал с модулем SEO Pro тоже не работает, поэтому его удалил. Что касается ЧПУ, они отображаются если включить в админку, но с ними не работает фильтр и сортировка. Если отключаю ЧПУ в админке, то фильтр и сортировка работают, вот такая ситуация в общем.